# Which ROS2 Distro? Iron or Humble?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, rosdistro, ros-iron

I have some experience on ROS and now planning to switch to ROS2.

Just installed a fresh Ubuntu 22.04. Which ROS2 distro should I use? **Iron or Humble?**

I am assuming Humble has more stable packages and options for a newcomer. But, if the Humble packages work on Iron too, that might change things.

On the other hand, Iron's EOL is pretty close (2024) compared to Humble's (2027). Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Humble can be a better choice as it has LTS, there will be more stable package releases and more support on he core. Also you can discuss this type of topics at [discourse.ros.org](https://discourse.ros.org/)